# How to avoid Devise from loading its default views when it does not find the right one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have the following:
Customized controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
...
end
```

Generated devise scoped views and then moved the from views/devise to views/users/ where we can find the views/users/registrations/new.html.erb

config/routes.rb - added the controllers:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,  controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

It is working fine, the customized user sign up view is rendering properly. The point is that I want to make it to fall in a missing template error. If I change the views folders name to views/foofoo/registrations it loads the devise sign up default view. I can't figure out how to avoid that. i would like it to raise an error (missing template or cant find a route). I tried to use `skip: :registrations`, but no success.

As the Devise docs says "if no view is found within the scope, Devise will use the default view". In few words, I dont want it to use default view when dont find the right one.